# Tomcat loading empty page

Tags: tomcat, centos, tomcat8, centos6.5

I installed Tomcat 8 on a CentOS 6.6 server and did SSH tunneling to view the "successfully installed" page but all I get when I go to [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080) is an empty page and when I checked my terminal I get the following error:

> channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

But I tested it out with httpd start command and the localhost showed the Apache server page. I was wondering if anybody has a possible solution for this. I have googled around it came out to no help. I followed *[Installing Maven Ant and Tomcat](http://www.unixmen.com/install-apache-ant-maven-tomcat-centos-76-5/)*

Comment: 8080 is Tomcat's http-Port, httpd is the Apache Webserver. Which one do you want to use? Is Tomcat running at all?

Comment: Tomcat is the preference...And I turned off the Apache Webserver. I only used the Apache Webserver to test if I successfully ssh tunneled to the server. But my main goal is try getting Tomcat to work so I can port my Java app onto it.

Comment: Ok, so are you sure that Tomcat is actually running? Check for an active Java process. What's in tomcat/logs directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue was with the network and I can officially close this question. Sorry about the trouble.